# Linking Microsoft Outlook to only SMTP Server and not IMAP/POP

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, smtp, pop3

I am trying to link my emails to my accounting software server, but I don't want Outlook to download the mails.

Is it possible to link just the SMTP server and leave out the IMAP/POP3 settings without getting errors.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to add an send-only account?

When adding the account, you will always need to input POP/IMAP and SMTP server information. After adding successfully, you can configure it as a send as account.

Please check the details in this article: [Exclude account from receiving (send only account)](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/308)

Comment: Thank you @Perry. This is exactly what I was looking for.